# Why can't I use the plist I created?

Tags: iphone, plist

I created a plist called list.plist, I just can't read the information in it.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *datapath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list.plist"];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:datapath];
self.tableDataSource = array;
NSLog(@"%d", [tableDataSource count]);
```

When I run it, it says the count is 0, but if I change file name to Elements.plist(a plist from the sample code from Apple), it will work. The two files are in the same path. list.plist is written by myself, it won't work even I copy the dictionary from elements.plist to list.plist.

Answer (score 0):

File names are case-sensitive on iOS, FYI. Also, try renaming the Elements.plist from the sample to list.plist and trying again. Maybe it's about file contents, not about file name.

Comment: If I rename the Element.plist to list.plist, it doesn't work! But if I  rename it to list1.plist, it works! No matter what the name of the list.plist(the file I created) renamed to, it never works.

Comment: Is list.plist, by any chance, the name of your project's info plist, the one that serves as application manifest on iOS? Check in the project settings. That file is somewhat special.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the file you created is included in the "Copy Resources" phase of your build. This is necessary to make sure it gets copied from your project's directory to the location of the bundle at runtime.

In Xcode 4, you can do by selecting the project at the top of the project navigator.Click on the "Build Phases" tab and expand the "Copy Bundle Resources" section. You should see a list of files there that get copied. If you see the Elements.plist file but not list.plist, then that is your problem. Drag list.plist from the project navigator to the list of copied files and rebuild.

Comment: I recommend you add an NSLog after you set dataPath to see what path you are trying to access when running in the simulator. Once you know the full path that it is trying to load, look via the finder to see if that path exists. If everything looks good there, you might next consider posting the contents of your plist file: Perhaps there's something off in it formatting.

Comment: The NSLog result is something like /user/....../Reg3.app/list.plist, I can't find it in the finder, because I can just find Reg3.app file. If I change the path in the code to full path like /Users/terry/Documents/Reg3/Reg3/list.plist, the problem still exists.

Comment: Now the problem is that it works when I use full path and won't work use the code below.                                           NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *datapath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"list.plist"]; Is it a problem about sandbox? I know little about sandbox, who can help me ?

Comment: Instead of assembling the path yourself, try using [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list" ofType:@"plist"];